# How to blur some portion of Image in Android?

Tags: android, image-processing, android-canvas, motion-blur

I am working in a project where I have to show some portion of the image clear and make rest part of the image blur. The blur should be managed by slider. Means it can be increase or decrease. The final result image should look alike below.

During my research for this I found below links useful

1. http://blog.neteril.org/blog/2013/08/12/blurring-images-on-android/
2. https://github.com/kikoso/android-stackblur
3. http://blog.neteril.org/blog/2013/08/12/blurring-images-on-android/

But the issue in above links is they all make complete image blur. Not some part of image.

Kindly suggest some solution to achieve this. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: How about using a blurred image in the foreground with a clipping mask and the normal image in the background?

Comment: check if this helps - https://gist.github.com/ryanbateman/6667995

Comment: @MD1948 Thanks for the comment, but that solution wont work because it is not know where to show clear and where to show blury user chooses this by using touch move effect. So where he drop the touch that portion is clear and rest is blurry.

Comment: @DroidWormNarendra this seems same which I mentioned in above link.

Comment: @sanchitsingh probably you need to recalculate the picture on every click?

Comment: @MD1948 Yes correct. So, I am looking for the way by which I can dynmically create blur image with some portion clear and rest blur.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

do a masked blur few times ....

1. **create mask**

   `0` means blur (black) and `>=1` means not blur (white). Init this part by big enough value for example `w=100` pixels

   [image: blur mask]
2. **create masked blur function**

   just a common convolution with some matrix like

   ```
   0.0 0.1 0.0
   0.1 0.6 0.1
   0.0 0.1 0.0
   ```

   but do it only for target pixels where mask is `==0` after image is blurred blur also the mask. This should enlarge the white area a bit (by pixel per iteration but losing magnitude on borders that is why `w>1`).
3. **loop bullet #2 `N` times**

   `N` determines blur/non-blur gradient depth the `w` is only to assure that burred mask will grow... Each time the blur mask will increase its white part

That should do the trick, You can also use dilatation of the mask instead of blurring it.

**[edit1] implementation**

Have played with this a bit today and found out that the mask is not growing enough with smooth so I change the algo a bit (here mine code C++):

```cpp
picture pic0,pic1,pic2;
    // pic0 - source
    // pic1 - output
    // pic2 - mask
int x0=400,y0=330,r0=100,dr=200;
    // x0,y0,r0 - masked area
    // dr - blur gradient size
int i,r;

// init output as sourceimage
pic1=pic0;
// init mask (size of source image) with gradient circles
pic2.resize(pic0.xs,pic0.ys);
pic2.clear(0);
for (i=1;i<=255;i++)
    {
    r=r0+dr-((dr*i)>>8);
    pic2.bmp->Canvas->Brush->Color=TColor(i<<16); // shifted because GDI has inverse channel layout then direct pixel access
    pic2.bmp->Canvas->Pen  ->Color=TColor(i<<16);
    pic2.bmp->Canvas->Ellipse(x0-r,y0-r,x0+r,y0+r);
    }
for (i=1;i<255;i+=10) pic1.rgb_smooth_masked(pic2,i);
```

here the smooth function:

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void picture::rgb_smooth_masked(const picture &mask,DWORD treshold)
    {
    int i,x,y;
    color *q0,*q1,*m0,c0,c1,c2;
    if ((xs<2)||(ys<2)) return;
    for (y=0;y<ys-1;y++)
        {
        q0=p[y  ]; m0=mask.p[y];
        q1=p[y+1];
        for (x=0;x<xs-1;x++)
         if (m0[x].dd<treshold)
            {
            c0=q0[x];
            c1=q0[x+1];
            c2=q1[x];
            for (i=0;i<4;i++)
             q0[x].db[i]=DWORD((DWORD(c0.db[i])+DWORD(c0.db[i])+DWORD(c1.db[i])+DWORD(c2.db[i]))>>2);
            }
        }
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

1. **create gradient mask with circles increasing in color from `1` to `255`**

   rest is black the gradient width is `dr` and determine the smoothing sharpness.
2. **create smooth masked with mask and threshold**

   smooth all pixels where mask pixel is < threshold. See the function `rgb_smooth_masked`. It uses `2x2` convolution matrix

   ```
   0.50,0.25
   0.25,0.00
   ```
3. **loop threshold from `1` to `255` by some step**

   the step determines the image blur strength.

And finally here some visual results this is source image I taken with my camera:

[image: horec flowers]

And here the output on the left and mask on the right:

[image: blur with mask and treshold]

the blue color means `values < 256` (B is lowest 8 bits of color)

I use my own picture class for images so some members are:

- `xs,ys` size of image in pixels
- `p[y][x].dd` is pixel at `(x,y)` position as 32 bit integer type
- `clear(color)` - clears entire image
- `resize(xs,ys)` - resizes image to new resolution

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Spektre . Here there is a problem. I can not use static image for masking because the requirement is to make clear area where ever user tap on the image. It means if user touches corner area of the image then it should be clear and rest blur. So how can we use static upper image for masking.

Comment: @sanchitsingh I do not see a problem there ... you clear the mask with black and draw disc,ellipse,oval,whatever in white where user touch .... center is the touch start position and size can be done from position where user stop touching/dragging or on some scrollbar ...

Comment: @sanchitsingh had a litlle time mood this morning for this so I busted it for fun see [edit1] for the C++ code and results have some changes in the algo too to make it more visually pleasing to me...