# Unblur part of an image where the mouse hovers over

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I've been trying to have an image which appears blurred but when the mouse hovers over, it clears that tiny bit where the cursor points. Much alike the [www.canva.com](http://www.canva.com) website.

Here is my code so far, it's not working 100%. I'm using HTML, CSS and Javascript. Unfortunately, I'm completely new to javascript!

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>QuoteWall</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/javascript" href="javascript.js">
    </head>
<body>
<div class="pic">
    <svg class="blur" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="100%">
        <image filter="url(#filter2)" xlink:href="image.png" width="100%" height="100%"></image>
        <filter id="filter2">
            <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="5" />
        </filter>
        <mask id="mask1">
            <circle cx="-50%" cy="-50%" r="30" fill="white" filter="url(#filter2)" />
        </mask>
        <image xlink:href="image.png" width="100%" height="100%" mask="url(#mask1)"></image>
    </svg>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
}
.pic {
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    height: 250px;
}
.blur {
    height: 100%;
}
.overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Javascript:

```
   $('.pic').mousemove(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var upX = event.clientX;
    var upY = event.clientY;
    var mask = $('#mask1 circle')[0];
    mask.setAttribute("cy", (upY - 5) + 'px');
    mask.setAttribute("cx", upX + 'px');
});
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks,
Joe

Comment: I don't understand. Do you want to unblur part of image on hover or do you want to unblur the complete image on hover ?

Comment: I want to unblur where the mouse is, so part of the image. Very similar to this: www.canva.com

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an experimental solution. You dynamically inject a new circle element in your svg mask each mouseover then you hide each circle with a delay.

```js
var svgNS = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";

$('.pic').mousemove(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var upX = event.clientX;
    var upY = event.clientY;
    var mask = $('#mask1')[0];
    
    var circle = document.createElementNS(svgNS,"circle");
    circle.setAttribute("cx", upX);
    circle.setAttribute("cy", upY);
    circle.setAttribute("r", "30");
    circle.setAttribute("fill", "white");
    circle.setAttribute("filter", "url(#filter2)");
    
    mask.appendChild(circle);
    
    setTimeout(function(){ 
        circle.style.opacity = '0';
        setTimeout(function(){ 
            mask.removeChild(circle);
        }, 300);
    }, 300);
});
```

```css
.pic {
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    height: 250px;
}
.blur {
    height: 100%;
}
.overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    height: 100%;
}
circle {
   opacity: 1;
   -webkit-transition: opacity 200ms linear;
   transition: opacity 200ms linear;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="pic">
    <svg class="blur" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="100%">
        <image filter="url(#filter2)" xlink:href="http://sport-nc.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/India_Surf_Tours_-_17__1_.jpg" width="100%" height="100%"></image>
        <filter id="filter2">
            <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="5" />
        </filter>
        <mask id="mask1">
            <circle cx="-50%" cy="-50%" r="30" fill="white" filter="url(#filter2)" />
        </mask>
        <image xlink:href="http://sport-nc.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/India_Surf_Tours_-_17__1_.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" mask="url(#mask1)"></image>
    </svg>
</div>
```

Your HTML should be like this with jQuery before the script I gave you. You have to respect the hierarchy of your scripts.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>QuoteWall</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"> //The css I gave you
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script> //jQuery here
        <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript.js"></script> //The script I gave you
    </head>
<body>
  <div class="pic">
    <svg class="blur" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="100%">
      <image filter="url(#filter2)" xlink:href="http://sport-nc.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/India_Surf_Tours_-_17__1_.jpg" width="100%" height="100%"></image>
      <filter id="filter2">
        <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="5" />
      </filter>
      <mask id="mask1">
        <circle cx="-50%" cy="-50%" r="30" fill="white" filter="url(#filter2)" />
      </mask>
      <image xlink:href="http://sport-nc.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/India_Surf_Tours_-_17__1_.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" mask="url(#mask1)"></image>
    </svg>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi @smdsgn ! This looks very interesting, I've given it a go and it's still coming with just a blurred image:/ It's working perfectly in the preview on stackoverflow! Perhaps it's the way I'm putting the javascript/Jquery and CSS in the HMTL file? Thanks for the reply though, it's really helpful:))

Comment: You probably missed something. Be careful to add jQuery before the script I gave you. If you create a fiddle with your new code, I could tell you what's wrong.

Comment: Here's a fiddle with the code: https://jsfiddle.net/uhs3d0ex/1/                              Thanks again smdsgn

Comment: Thanks for the fiddle! Just trying to change images etc! Thanks for your help man:)

Comment: If i were to add a new image from my files, how would i do that? The src="" doesn't seem to be working in the <image>. Sorry to be a bother.

Comment: Just change the xlink:href for both image elements. Don't forget to accept the answer if this code helped you.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you give id to the div where image is being rendered, So considering id of your image div is divImage like : 
HTML:

```
<div id="divImage">
//Your Image inside this div
</div>
```

So in your JS you can write :

```
$("#divImage").hover(function(){
//Your Complete on hover function here.
})
```

I guess this should work.

Answer (score 0):

I would use this [How to blur some portion of Image](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30102057/2521214).

1. **have some blur mask** (fully filled with blur)
2. **Handle `OnMouseMove` event**

   Just clear the blur in mask area around actual mouse position during mouse movement.
3. **On some periodic event like `OnTimer`**

   blur out the mask so any cleared space is diminishing with time. Then apply masked blur (from linked Q/A) on your image and paint it into your viewing area.