# Variable strength gaussian blurring of an image

Tags: python, image-processing

Is there a way to apply gaussian blurring to an image where each pixel is blurred using its own standard deviation which is passed as a mask? I want to be able to apply stronger blurring to certain parts of the image depending on some condition. Ideally, this would be something like
blurred=variable_gauss(image (HxWx3), std_mask (HxW))

Comment: You could simply use a sliding window which computes each "condition" as it passes and applies the blur.

Comment: That would be painfully slow in python. By condition I just mean a pre-calculated mask of floats which shows the strength of blurring. 
Actually, I don't really need blurring to be gaussian. It's just that gaussian blurring looks good.

Comment: What will be the SD of the blur? only to be applied to the voxel? in that case you could simply apply a matrix multiplication if i understand correctly

Comment: The mask would contain SD for individual pixels.
The x3 refers to RGB channels (not real voxels and gaussian does not need to be 3D), so blurring would be applied equally to each channel. It's not really needed there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to blur some portion of Image in Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30101044/how-to-blur-some-portion-of-image-in-android)